# Clarification on generic class declaration

Tags: java, generics

Please explain what's the difference between these 2 definitions:

```
public class Box<T implements Comparable<T>>
```

and

```
public class Box<T> implements Comparable<T>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one won't even compile. It should be `public class Box<T extends Comparable<T>>`. It means that the Box class has a generic type parameter that implements `Comparable<T>` interface.

The second means that `Box` class has a generic type parameter, and in addition `Box<T>` implements the interface `Comparable<T>`.

Comment: so are they both the same thing

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald No. In the first case, T is the class that implements Comparable. In the second case, Box is the class that implements Comparable.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Also please could you give an example code of the question above

Answer (score 2):

In the first definition, the type `T` implements `Comparable`, in the second definition the class `Box` implements `Comparable`.